# How can I make fire in BGE?

Tags: game-engine

I've seen a lot of tutorials with fire in Blender Game Engine and how they have particles. They're great and all, but when I go ahead and try to make it this is what it says. [image]

I can't use particles, and there are absolutely no tutorials for fire in Blender Game Engine for 2.79 (my version), and none from 2016 - 2017. I really need help.

Comment: Offtopic: Go invest your time in Unity or Unreal, it's also free and it's modern with all the tools you need and with plenty documentation and tutorials. BGE is not worth your time as of now, not even with eevee in near future.

Comment: You should post your comment in the unity forums. This is a Blender website. It is not worth your time talking about Unity and Unreal. It does not help answering the question at all.

Comment: @Monster Do you really think there is no merit in my comment and I wasted my time suggesting this? The comment is meant for Blender users, not Unity users, what good it would make in Unity forum? Because this is Blender website is it forbidden to point out alternatives? It does not help to answer because it is not an answer but an offtopic comment, I hope these are not forbidden too.. If yes I will comply with the inquisition next time and censor my mouth not to speak about the world outside of Blender...

Answer (score 1):

## Blender

Blender particles are not supported by the BGE. Due to the complexity and inefficiency they will not be supported in the near future (at least not in a way that they can be useful in a game).

## BGE Particles

Particles in the BGE are ordinary objects. They are nothing special. All you do is you dynamically create a lot of them.

A simple way is to use the Object Actuator in Add Object mode. When activated the actuator will add a copy of the referred object.

To get flames, sparks and smoke you add different objects. Each object can animate over time (position, location, material). This all together can create the illusion of fire.

Due to the complexity of that topic I do not want to go into much detail here.

I suggest to search for BGE fire tutorials. There should be plenty out there.

## Pre-rendered textures

An alternative / additional way is to use textures with pre-rendered and animated flames.